# WordPress archive page for multiple taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, wordpress

I want to ask if it is possible to make WP archives page that arranges the custom posts in specific way. Let me explain.
The CPT is "Products". All the products have several custom taxonomies. Ex. 
Product>Fall 2014>Shampoo     (there is only one shampoo from this Fall 2014 collection)
Product>Fall 2014>Conditioner (there is only one conditioner from this Fall 2014 collection)

I want to add the corresponding Winter 2014> Shampoo and Winter 2014 > Conditioner but I want to be able to display them in the following order (masonry style):

```
     Fall 2014:
```

Shampoo           Conditioner

```
    Winter 2014:
```

Shampoo           Conditioner

Also I want to be able to categorize them by product type like:

```
    Shampoos
```

Fall 2014   Winter 2014

```
    Conditioners
```

Fall 2014   Winter 2014

In the end to explain the relation between the taxonomies and CPT.
Shampoo1( Custom post type - Products) which has the taxonomies Shampoo (parent taxonomy) and Fall 2014 (child taxonomy).

Is something like this possible to be made so the process of sorting will be made by wordpress with each new product, and if it is possible can someone point me in the right direction because I am lost :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. By creating custom taxonomy templates for all your taxonomies and so your posts relevant to certain taxonomies will be showing up in your taxonomy template. For example if your custom taxonomy is Shampoo, then your taxonomy page will become **taxonomy-shampoo.php**  in this way you can create templates for all other taxonomies to show your products according to your needs, for reference check https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/